# `source .../settings.csh` not working from `sh ./test.sh`

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, tcsh, csh

I want to source Xilinx ise `setiin64.csh` file with the `source` command.

I have

```
source /home/xilinx/ise_14.5/14.5/ISE_DS/settings64.csh
```

in another file, `test.sh`. So I want to run only `test.sh` file as

```
sh ./test.sh
```

But I am not getting Xilinx ISE 14.5 version when I do `which ise`.

If I execute command

```
source /home/xilinx/ise_14.5/14.5/ISE_DS/settings64.csh
```

directly in terminal then it works fine.

Comment: If you have a script `test.sh` using a Bourned-dervied Shell such as `sh`  or `bash`, then it should reference the `settings64.sh` file. If your shell is C Shell (`/bin/csh`) then you should use `settings64.csh`. It's really not a good idea to try and mix'n'match between the two different shell families.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the `setiin64.csh` C-shell script is compatible with `sh`, `source /home/xilinx/ise_14.5/14.5/ISE_DS/settings64.csh` from a `sh` shell should not work. But you say it does, so I will have to take your word for it.

You can not write a script that sources this file an run it with `sh test.sh` and expect that the environment variables will be set in the *current* shell environment.

The `sh test.sh` sets up a new environment in which the `source` command will be used to source `setiin64.csh` (I still find it hard to believe this will actually work, it's a `csh` script). This new environment will be deleted once `test.sh` is done executing. No variable set therein will be transferred to the outermost environment (your shell session).

You could

```
source test.sh
```

But that's doing exactly what you did from the start, and you might as well source a symbolic link to `/home/xilinx/ise_14.5/14.5/ISE_DS/settings64.csh` instead.

The best solution is probably just to source the file from the command line (or from one of your your shell initialization files).

Comment: If `source settings64.csh` works on the command line, it probably indicates that Vish is using csh on the command line.